# Passing newlines using PHP to a textarea

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a list of email addresses (each one on a new line). I pull the array from my database, explode it along the comma delimiter, and run it through a foreach loop.

```
$emailsList = "";
foreach($emails as $email)
{ 
    $emailsList = $emailsList . "\n" . $email;
}
echo "Additional Report Emails<textarea name='showReportsEmails'>".$emailsList."</textarea>";
```

When I look in the textarea itself, it will literally show the line break tag in the textarea. What can I do to get rid of this and have the text behave as I want?

```
<br />
email1@gmail.com<br />
 email2@gmail.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484985/html-display-line-breaks-within-textarea

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when the result is printed in the textarea, the PHP new lines (`\n`) are converted to `<br/>`s. So, maybe there's a nl2br() function being used to output the result into the textarea. It should be fixed by removing that. Otherwise, you can use the code below when setting the textarea's content:

```
<textarea><?php echo implode("\n", array_map('trim', explode("\n", strip_tags($emailsList)))); ?></textarea>
```

The code above first removes all html tags from the `$emailsList` variable, and then also removes white spaces before and after lines, so you would be good to go with this.

Comment: Interesting. This removed one of the breaks but not both.

Comment: @AKor I don't know if it didn't work because of a dumb mistake I've done. I forgot to include the PHP tags and echo the output. Can you check the updated code?

Comment: @AKor I updated the code again, and instead of `trim()`, which seems to be removing the white spaces at the beginning and at the end of the content, I used `implode()`, `array_map()` and `explode()` to remove the white spaces for each line.

Comment: Nope, no luck. Still both break tags are present. I can't seem to be rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

The name suggest the the element can only hold text. It doesn't parse as `HTML` rather it does so as text.

I tested this code:

```
<?php
$value = "Hello,\nname\nis\nScript47.";

echo "<textarea>$value</textarea>";
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Edit 1:**

You could also use `\r` to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Carriage returns instead of HTML code in the textarea.
`\r`