# populating textarea with javascript, adding line breaks

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate the value of a textarea in my html with javascript.  My script below basically does that, however I'm trying to figure out how to insert a line break in my value (between 'date' and 'text').

Basically, as written, my script gives this result...

*On Dec. 25 you replied: Merry Christmas!*

However, I would like it to read as...

*On Dec. 25 you replied:

Merry Christmas!*

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = `On ${date} you replied: ${text}`;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just hit ENTER after `replied:` in the template literal.

Comment: Wouldn't this existing post work for you?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485082/1188197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add \n in the string to push it to a new line.

```
  <script>
    let date= "11/01/2020";
    let text= "Merry Christmas!";
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").value= `On ${date} you replied: \n${text}`;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you.  as posted below, I must have typed it in wrong initially.  stupid brain lapse.

Answer (score 1):

Simple add the new line escape sequence character: `\n`

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = `On ${date} you replied: \n${text}`;
}
</script>
```

Comment: duh, I had tried that and it wasn't working, but I stupidly had typed  it in wrong initially.

thanks.

Comment: @rickel_pick welcome. great to be of help